# SQL join two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a bit lost here. I would like to join these two queries into one to avoid two connections and simplify the code.

```
 "SELECT uname FROM Projects WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)"

 "SELECT name FROM Users WHERE username like"+"'"+ uname +"'"
```

Right now I am using two queries and taking the result of the first into the second one.
I am sure the two queries can become one but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `=` rather than `LIKE` since I you are not using pattern symbol such as `%`.

```
SELECT  a.name
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Projects b
            ON a.username = b.uname
WHERE   b.ID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this using the `INNER JOIN` considering that both of your tables are linked through `User_ID`

```
SELECT  u.name
FROM    Users u INNER JOIN Projects p ON u.username = p.uname
WHERE   p.ID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help  but I was trying to avoid the uname variable.

Comment: @FeliceM:- Yes although I have updated my answer now ;) Hope  that will also work

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks to all of you guys. I was really lost.

Comment: @FeliceM:- But I would suggest you to go with INNER JOINS as they are better than subqueries

Answer (score 1):

i think the following query will work:

```
SELECT name FROM Users WHERE username in 
    (SELECT uname FROM Projects WHERE id IN 
        (SELECT      MAX(id) FROM Projects))
```

Comment: Bingo! This one is working perfectly. +, the cinese guy answers first and is also working. Thanks a lot.